# Pass data from one view controller to another and store

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

How to pass data from First View Controller to Second View Controller and this data will store in Second View Controller even after i close and remove the application at background. Is it possible to do this

FirstViewController

```
let type = self.arrayAddress[indexPath.row].addressType // Here getting value name "eg: Home"
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(type, forKey: "type")
let typeAfter = userDefaults.string(forKey: "type")!
print(typeAfter) // Home
```

SecondViewController

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let typeAfter = userDefaults.string(forKey: "type")!
self.lblLocationValue.text = typeAfter // Home
```

Comment: 1. how is first view controller and second view controller are related to each other? 2. What have you tried to store data till now? There is user default , core data, writing data to file on disk, realm, how about saving data in backend server and fetching it on launch? You see where I am going with this? Without proper details answer can be as vague as possible, also this kind of question will be closed because you havent added any debug details and finally SO is not a site to get code for your project, we can only help if you have technical difficulty

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Please check the updated question

Comment: Whats the issue? You are already saving data into user default in first view controller and reading it in second? You want to save data into user default in second view controller only?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Issue is that stored data is not displaying after close and again open the app

Comment: Thats not possible, if you save the data to userdefault once it will be there may be when you relaunch first view controller loads first and it resets? Or do you have a code which deletes all data in user default?